# Compare a map's value with another map value in groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I have a requirement where I want to check `a map's value` with another `map's value` if it matches I'd like to get the `key` of 1st map

virtualization map

```
def virtua=[
    "VMWARE"        :   "00:68:8B:",
    "VMWARE"        :   "00:68:8A",
    "COLINUX"       :   "00:18:8A:"
]
```

network map

```
def network=[
    "eth0":"00:68:8B:",
    "eth1":"00:18:8A:",
    "eth2":"00:68:8A:"
]
```

So after matching values from `network` & `virtua` I get the below output, how can i do it in groovy?

```
eth0,00:68:8B:,VMWARE
eth1,00:18:8A:,COLINUX
eth2,00:68:8A:,VMWARE
```

**Update** After **@tim_yates** & **@Xaerxess** answer, I thought it's best if I had MAC Addr as keys as `VMWARE` can be duplicate

```
def virtua1=[
"00:68:8B:"     :   "VMWARE",
"00:68:8A:"     :   "VMWARE",
"00:18:8A:"     :   "COLINUX"
]

def coll = network.collect { k, v ->   
    //[ k, v, virtua.find { a, b -> b == v }?.key ]
    print "$k,$v,"
    println virtua1.find{ a, b -> a == v }?.value
}
```

**Output**

```
eth0,00:68:8B:,VMWARE
eth1,00:18:8A:,COLINUX
eth2,00:68:8A:,VMWARE
```

Comment: It would be easier if you used MAC address as key in both maps (BTW: `network` is a list, not map).

Comment: @Xaerxess: Oh! My bad, `network` is a Map :) Also supposing the MAC addr is key, can you show me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have duplicate keys in a map (you have multiple `VMWARE` entries), and your network variable is a list not a map...

Correcting these, and assuming you mean:

```
def virtua=[
    "VMWAREA"       :   "00:68:8B:",
    "VMWAREB"       :   "00:68:8A:",
    "COLINUX"       :   "00:18:8A:"
]
def network=[
    "eth0":"00:68:8B:",
    "eth1":"00:18:8A:",
    "eth2":"00:68:8A:",
]
```

you can do:

```
def coll = network.collect { k, v ->
  [ k, v, virtua.find { a, b -> b == v }?.key ]
}
```

To give you the list:

```
[ ["eth0", "00:68:8B:", "VMWAREA"],
  ["eth1", "00:18:8A:", "COLINUX"],
  ["eth2", "00:68:8A:", "VMWAREB"] ]
```

And if you want that printed out as comma separated Strings, you can just do:

```
coll*.join(',').each { println it }
```

#### Edit -- key:list example

In the comments, I was asked about a Map with values as Lists (to get around the duplicate key problem);

```
def virtua=[
    "VMWARE"  : [ "00:68:8B:", "00:68:8A:" ],
    "COLINUX" : [ "00:18:8A:" ]
]
def network=[
    "eth0":"00:68:8B:",
    "eth1":"00:18:8A:",
    "eth2":"00:68:8A:",
]
network.each { k, v ->
  println "$k,$v,${virtua.find { it.value.grep( v ) }?.key}"
}
```

Comment: My bad, it was a typo in the question, In my program i am generating `network map`

Comment: it gives me `00:68:8B:
00:68:8B:
00:68:8A
00:18:8A:
00:68:8B:
00:68:8A
00:18:8A:`

Comment: @Ricky have you solved the duplicate key problems with `virtua`?  Can you post some actual data that you are testing this with?  Your `network` map is still wrong in the question, as you're missing the commas

Comment: @Ricky whoops...left some debug in the `collect`...removed now ;-)

Comment: Sorry for my typos, also i think I might need to change `VMWARE` being  value as I can have multiple `VMWARE`'s.. I m guessing I cannot have duplicate `keys` in a map?

Comment: @Ricky No you can't, but you can have a key pointing to a list ie; `def network = [ "VMWARE" : [ "00:68:8B:", "00:68:8A" ] ]`

Comment: it would be nice if you can give an example with `a key pointing to a list` Thanks